# List Implementation in different scenerios

Tags: java, list, memory-management

I have a very simple question that I would like to ask. There are 2 ways by which you initialize a variable :

1.

```
List<SalesReturnJson> salesReturnJsons=new LinkedList<>();
salesReturnJsons=salesRepository.findSales();
```

2.

```
List<SalesReturnJson> salesReturnJsons=salesRepository.findSales();
```

So in this 2 scenerios how is the memory allocated and In the second scenerio which implementation(`LinkedList` or `ArrayList`) of `List` is called.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is returned by method `findSales()` ? `ArrayList` instance or `LinkedList` ?

Comment: In the first scenario you're creating a `LinkedList` for no reason. Then you throw it away.

Answer (score 1):

If in the first scenario the second line is exactly below the first line, the "new" statement would have no effect. You create an empty LinkedList, put a reference on it, then you change the reference to point to another List (I suppose findSales returns a List) and finally the garbage collector of java will erase the empty LinkedList, since there is no reference to it anymore.

In the second scenario you return a List (as I suppose) and put a reference to this List.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases an object returned by `salesRepository.findSales()` will be assigned to your variable. Since the implementation is the same in both cases, without knowing the actual implementation we can only say that the object will be of the same class in both cases, however, creating an object and then re-assigning the variable to another reference as in your first example makes little sense. The second will achieve the same result, but with reduced effort.

Answer (score 0):

Both scenarios end up with exactly the same List in your `salesReturnJsons` variable, with the List type being the one returned by `salesRepository.findSales()`. From the code given, we can't tell what type is actually returned from this method.

The only difference is, the first scenario creates an absolutely unnecessary empty LinkedList, stores it into your `salesReturnJsons` variable, and immediately replaces it by the list from `salesRepository.findSales()`, making the LinkedList garbage. So, please use the second version.

If (for whatever special reason) your intent might be to have a LinkedList of the `salesRepository.findSales()` results, then you could do:

```
List<SalesReturnJson> salesReturnJsons=
    new LinkedList<SalesReturnJson>(salesRepository.findSales());
```

That will copy the elements from the method result into a fresh LinkedList, then you are sure about the List type.

But the typical code snippet would be your version 2.